# Using repository in admin form magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I using admin form from this [example](https://git.pablomalo.fr/polo/jeff-contacts/-/tree/master)

But i want change modelFactory from model to repository

But i don`t know how do it.

I need to change this files from model to repository

```
    <?php

namespace Jeff\Contacts\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Jeff\Contacts\Model\ContactFactory;

class Delete extends Action
{

    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Index';

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $contactFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ContactFactory $contactFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $contact = $this->contactFactory->create()->load($id);

        if(!$contact)
        {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Unable to process. please, try again.'));
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/', array('_current' => true));
        }

        try{
            $contact->delete();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Your contact has been deleted !'));
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Error while trying to delete contact'));
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

And this file:

```
    <?php
namespace Jeff\Contacts\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Jeff\Contacts\Model\ContactFactory;

class Save extends Action
{

    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Index';

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $contactFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ContactFactory $contactFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if($data)
        {
            try{
                $id = $data['jeff_contacts_contact_id'];

                $contact = $this->contactFactory->create()->load($id);

                $data = array_filter($data, function($value) {return $value !== ''; });

                $contact->setData($data);
                $contact->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Successfully saved the item.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData($data);
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $contact->getId()]);
            }
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you make repository class?

Comment: yes i have repository class

Comment: Does your repository class has required methods i-e `delete`, `save`...?

Comment: i have method delete,save,getbyid,deletebyid

Answer (score 0):

This is `Save` controller using `Repository`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Article;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use \Magento\Backend\Helper\Js;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Article;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;
    protected $_backendJsHelper;

   
    private $articleFactory;
    private $articleRepository;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\ArticleFactory $articleFactory
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Api\ArticleRepositoryInterface $articleRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        Js $backendJsHelper,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ArticleFactory $articleFactory = null,
        \Vendor\Module\Api\ArticleRepositoryInterface $articleRepository = null
    ) {
           $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
           $this->_backendJsHelper = $backendJsHelper;
           $this->articleFactory = $articleFactory
            ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Vendor\Module\Model\ArticleFactory::class);
           $this->articleRepository = $articleRepository
            ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Vendor\Module\Api\ArticleRepositoryInterface::class);
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    /**
     * Authorization level
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::save');
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {
            if (isset($data['status']) && $data['status'] === 'true') {
                $data['status'] = Article::STATUS_ENABLED;
            }
            if (empty($data['article_id'])) {
                $data['article_id'] = null;
            }

            /** @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Article $model */
            $model = $this->articleFactory->create();

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('article_id');
            if ($id) {
                try {
                    $model = $this->articleRepository->getById($id);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This article no longer exists.'));
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
                }
            }

            $model->setData($data);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'article_article_prepare_save',
                ['article' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );

            try {
                $this->articleRepository->save($model);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the article.'));
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('article_article');
                
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['article_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e->getPrevious() ?:$e);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the article.'));
            }

            

            $this->dataPersistor->set('article_article', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['article_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('article_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Note : My module is related to `articles`, hope you can change where it's used according to your requirements.

Comment: I don`t can get id from  request         $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if($data)
        {
            try{
               // $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam ( 'id' );   return ""

Comment: How about getting this way? `$id = $data['jeff_contacts_contact_id'];`. I think your param name is different than `id`.

Comment: when i create new contact i can get id, I try  $id = $data['jeff_contacts_contact_id'];  and $ id = $ this-> getRequest () -> getParam ('jeff_contacts_contact_id'); in this cases i get $id = ""

Comment: That's something to do with the name of param passed in`getParam` method. I answered what you asked, using repository instead of modelFactory. Hope that's working fine.